# Need to create SQL query to the table devices, with 2 columns “Name Surname” and “OS” in response

Tags: mysql, sql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EK8ko.png)

You need to merge 2 columns into one and merge with another table. I found how to merge 2 columns into 1, but how to merge is not clear.

Merge 2 columns into 1:

```
SELECT concat(name,' ', surname) as 'Name Surname' FROM `user`;
```

My attempts to join with 2 columns of another table

```
SELECT device.OS FROM `user` RIGHT JOIN device ON user.name = device.name;
```

How to do it in 1st request???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unique value in your records seems to be the `Phone` and `phone_number`, and not the `Name`.
This is where you need to `JOIN` them.

It is where there is a match on the left table (`users`) with the right table (`devices`), based on the columns `Phone` (from `users` table) and `phone_number` (from `devices` table).

```
SELECT CONCAT(u.Name, " ", u.Surname) AS 'Name Surname', d.OS
FROM users u
JOIN devices d
ON u.Phone = d.phone_number
```